# Cannot delete file in windows 7. It sits on showing "discovering items"

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, file-permissions

I have two files in Videos Library. Both files are over 4.0GB in size. I cannot delete them. Whenever I try to delete, the dialogue box with discovering items shows up and keeps showing the same until I cancel. It also makes laptop slow even after cancellation. I tried cmd->dir. One file is listed in dir but the other is not. I have some other files of similar size. they are fine. Moreover the file which is not coming up by cmd->dir is not also showing in Documents->My Videos.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking in the Videos library? Also try running `chkdsk /f` on your drive.

Comment: @ShibliSaleheen: If you use the same login on Server Fault and Super User, you will be able to edit your question directly, and not have to “submit” edits to the review queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows 7 restart and open your computer in safe mode. Find the file you want to delete and delete. As simple as that.